# GNU Octave: Build a package from a directory instead of a tarball

Tags: installation, octave, package

I currently developing an interface for a library as a GNU Octave package. Normally packages in GNU Octave are installed via

```
pkg install tarball_of_the_package.tar.gz
```

But compressing the package for each test is more or less time consuming. Now my question is if it is possible to call somehow the `pkg install` mechanism from a directory which has a valid package structure like in the tarball? Running

```
pkg install .
```

from inside this directory yields an error:

```
unpack: FILETYPE must be "gunzip" for a directory
```

Even specifying the whole path as

```
pkg install /path/to/the/package/source
```

results in the same problem.

At the moment I am using GNU Octave 4.0.0 for my developments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What most packages have is a `Makefile` at the root of the package with targets such as `install` that will handle that for you. See for example the [`Makefile` for the statistics package](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/statistics/file/fe1b4734c353/Makefile) which allow you to do:

```
$ hg clone http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/statistics
destination directory: statistics
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 401 changesets with 996 changes to 172 files
updating to branch default
133 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ cd statistics/
$ make install
Creating package version 1.2.4 release ...
rm -rf "statistics-1.2.4"
hg archive --exclude ".hg*" --exclude "Makefile" --type files "statistics-1.2.4"
chmod -R a+rX,u+w,go-w "statistics-1.2.4"
tar cf - --posix "statistics-1.2.4" | gzip -9n > "statistics-1.2.4.tar.gz"
Installing package locally ...
octave --silent --eval 'pkg ("install", "statistics-1.2.4.tar.gz")'
For information about changes from previous versions of the statistics package, run 'news statistics'.
```

And of course, there's nothing stopping you from calling `make install` from the Octave session itself. The statistics package example is nicer because it only has m files. If your package also has code to be compiled, the image package has a more complex, but not by much, [Makefile](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/image/file/554d9840e69f/Makefile) for that.

Comment: Intresstingly, the way using `pkg install .` is used by the Debian people to package octave-forge software into a deb package and I can not find any difference or patch inside octave that enables this.